# What is the simplest way to parse binary files in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, parsing

Say I have a binary file (generated with Java) containing a 32 bit int value. I'm currently using the following Objective-C code for parsing it:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"dat"];
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

unsigned long intValue;
memcpy(&intValue, [[file readDataOfLength:4] bytes], 4);
intValue = NSSwapBigLongToHost(intValue);

[file closeFile];
```

My first question is to ask if it's the common way of doing things on the iPhone because I didn't find anything close to Java's DataInputStream.

My second question is related to the line of code with a memcpy. I don't undestand why the following part (more elegant, less "low-level") is not working instead:

```
[[file readDataOfLength:4] getbytes:&intValue];
```

I'm getting a warning on build:

```
'NSData' may not respond to '-getbytes:'
```

On execution, I'm getting:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData getbytes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last question, use getBytes (uppercase B).